# Android Studio and VSCode doesn't open my Flutter app on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my flutter app for Android Studio or VSCode but it doesn't work.
Here's the output:

```
 lib/main.dart
Xcode build done.                                           58.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/****/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:59:56: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                                                           ^~~~~~~
                                                           openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/***/Desktop/Flutter_MQTT-master 3 copy/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/local_auth/local_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:87:32: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      } else if (authError.code == LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled) {
                                   ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:32:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled,
        ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:111:34: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                case LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable:
                                     ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:29:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotAvailable") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable,
        ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:112:34: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                case LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled:
                                     ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:32:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled,
        ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:113:34: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDLockout' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryLockout [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                case LAErrorTouchIDLockout:
                                     ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:37:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDLockout' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDLockout NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_11, 10_13, 9_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryLockout")
        ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:139:10: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        case LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled:
             ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:32:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_13, 8_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled") = kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled,
        ^
    /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:149:10: warning: 'LAErrorTouchIDLockout' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - use LAErrorBiometryLockout [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        case LAErrorTouchIDLockout:
             ^
    In module 'LocalAuthentication' imported from /Users/***/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.6.3+4/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:4:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Headers/LAError.h:37:5: note: 'LAErrorTouchIDLockout' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        LAErrorTouchIDLockout NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_11, 10_13, 9_0, 11_0, "use LAErrorBiometryLockout")
        ^
    7 warnings generated.
    warning: /Users/***/Desktop/Flutter_MQTT-master 3 copy/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods_Runner.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeSignature: Failed to parse executable: Invalid read request. startingAt: 0, offsetBy: 0, typeSize: 4 (UInt32), dataSize: 0
    /Users/***/Desktop/Flutter_MQTT-master 3 copy/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

.............................................................................................................
But when I lunch the application from Xcode it works. What can be the problem?
I tried many things like locking and unlocking the keychain.
[image: This is my iOS folder inside my project]

Comment: use android emulator for android studio and vs code in windows but if you use mac os i suggest xcode that better ide in mac

Comment: But how can I write flutter program in Xcode?

Comment: From the error i can see the code is deprecated which is mapped to native iOS objective c. Can you check which flutter channel you are on? Try to run this flutter channel stable and then flutter upgrade and then get packages again. (I'm supposing you are using mac.)

Comment: Yes I am using a Mac, interestingly when I run flutter clean, etc in the an Android studio’s terminal it says flutter: not defined so I cannot use this tools but when I deleted the build folder it worked

Comment: How can I check in with flutter channel I am